# net::ERR_ABORTED 429 using ipinfo.io only over local host

Tags: javascript

I wanted to get a IP address from the front end devices. I found [this](https://ipinfo.io/developers) free API called IPINFO.io

As per the documentation to get the IP address using Jquery all I need to do is:

```
    $.get("https://ipinfo.io", function (response) {
        console.log(response.ip)
    }, "jsonp");
```

However, I get:

> net::ERR_ABORTED 429

I am running this locally using Nodejs. The server does not matter because I am not sending a request to my Nodejs server.

However, if I paste the same code in a codepen with the same jquery version as the one that I have in my Nodejs project it runs just fine.

Why am I getting this error only when I use it over localhost?

Comment: https://http.cat/429

Comment: I suggest trying out [ipregistry.co](https://ipregistry.co) for a higher free tier and no rate limits.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IPinfo.io returns a 429 status if you've been rate limited. The unauthenticated API limits at 1,000 requests per day. See https://ipinfo.io/developers for more details. If you signup for a free account you'll get an access token you can use, and a limit of 50,000 requests per month.

Comment: This answer doesn't explain why it would work in codepen but not localhost.

Comment: Because codepen hasn't been rate limited, but "localhost" has.

Comment: Just curious, would the rate limiter count requests from *domains* or from *ip addresses*?

Comment: @user1063287 it limits based on both IP and referring domain